# Нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "LPSTR"

Tags: c++, строки, winapi, указатели

Как исправить ошибку: значение типа "сonst char *" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "LPSTR" (ругается на имя канала)

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>



int main()
{
    // Флаг успешного создания канала
    BOOL   fConnected;

    // Идентификатор канала Pipe
    HANDLE hNamedPipe;

    // Имя создаваемого канала Pipe
    LPSTR  lpszPipeName = "\\\\.\\pipe\\$MyPipe$";

    // Буфер для передачи данных через канал
    char   szBuf[512];

    // Количество байт данных, принятых через канал
    DWORD  cbRead;

    // Количество байт данных, переданных через канал
    DWORD  cbWritten;

    printf("Named pipe server demo\n"
        "(C) A. Frolov, 1996, Email: frolov@glas.apc.org\n");

    // Создаем канал Pipe, имеющий имя lpszPipeName
    hNamedPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
        lpszPipeName,
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT,
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
        512, 512, 5000, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
char lpszPipeName[] = "\\\\.\\pipe\\$MyPipe$";
```

Дело в том, что `LPSTR` — это `char*`, т.е. указатель на *изменяемую* строку, а `"\\\\.\\pipe\\$MyPipe$"` — литерал, т.е. строка *неизменяемая*...

Comment: Исправил. Но ошибка никуда не делась. В поле hNamedPipe.lpszPipeName ругается на: аргумент типа "char *" несовместим с параметром типа "LPCWSTR"

Comment: Значит `wchar_t lpszPipeName[] = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\$MyPipe$";`

Comment: Можно встречный вопрос: вы работали с "узкими" символами — о чем говорит тип LPSTR. Как только получили ответ — тут же перешли на Unicode. Почему? Вы же поменяли само условие вопроса. Очень интересно спросить "сколько будет 7*7", а когда ответят, что 49, сказать, что на самом деле имелась в виду восьмеричная система счисления или что-то в этом роде...

Comment: Что-то за сегодня второй вопрос про wide char. Наверно Visual Studio или недавно перешла на wchar по-умолчанию, или давно перешла, просто по старым методичкам учатся. Как переключить проэкт c UNICODE на ANSI - быстро не скажу. Но изначально LPSTR, т.е. ANSI в вопросе.

Comment: Ещё можно явно указать  `CreateNamedPipeА` -  что нужна ANSI версия функции.

Comment: Ещё можно так: `LPSTR  lpszPipeName = (LPSTR)"\\\\.\\pipe\\$MyPipe$";` Разумеется, пытаться модифицировать строку через этот указатель не стоит))